# Intercepting the Move command in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, sdk, hook, dll-injection

I am working on a plugin for a document tagging software. I would like to intercept the MOVE operation in Windows explorer , and let the tagging software handle it instead .

I was thinking about Hooks, DLL injection . The MOVE can be initiated by several ways by the user, and I need to intercept all of them.

Does anyone have other ideas. It would be nice if you can post some example links too.

TIA

Sujay

Comment: What about all the other times a user might move? There's lots of different ways of moving even in Explorer. Some people use different shells. You can move from common dialogs. Etc. etc.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by hooking the move operation? Changing such a fundamental operation like this is a very bad idea; I suggest finding another way. Look at how TortoiseSVN handles this scenario for example, by adding another context menu item in Explorer, not by changing the one users already know & love.

Comment: @tenfour The tagging software cannot update its database , if the move is not intercepted . Please share if you have any different approach.

Comment: This is just not a reasonable solution. There's no way you can intercept all potential move operations. You need to find some other way to implement your software's database.

Comment: @Code Gray - Cant we trap WM_NOTIFY to see if the move has occurred.

Comment: No. You don't get a `WM_NOTIFY` message when the user moves a file on their disk.

Answer (score 0):

Detours is the wrong solution for this problem.

Instead, consider using something like a FileSystemWatcher http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7t1d0ky or a kernel-mode Filesystem filter driver.